# O uso de engines no Rails 4 funciona da mesma forma que no Rails 3.x?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, engine

Mediante a várias pesquisas nos últimos dias à respeito de modularização de aplicações com Rails, encontrei vasto material à respeito de Engines em Rails 3.x, mas praticamente nada referente ao Rails 4. Pedi referências para um amigo e ele me disse que na versão 4 do framework, a modularização deve ser feita exclusivamente através de *gems*. Achei meio absurdo, dada a aparente facilidade que as engines fornecem.

## Pergunta:

Em Rails 4 o uso de engines se dá na mesma forma que suas versões anteriores (3.x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi, o suporte para os chamados plugins foi descontinuado no rails 4. No entanto ao criar um novo engine isso é transparente. No entanto o que se faz ao gerar um novo engine é na verdade criar uma gem.

No guide já tem um tutorial a explicar os passos todos para criar um engine em rails 4.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html